# Overriding default STI behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a STI setup with profiles. A profile can be a user, or a page, however there are many types of users and profiles. Ex:

```
profile
  -user
    --member
    --admin
    --moderator
  -page
    --business
    --event
    --band
```

When I try to run the query

```
Profile::User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

The SQL that is generated

```
SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."type" IN ('Profile::User') AND "profiles"."email" = 'email@email.com' LIMIT 1
```

Since there are different types of users this query doesn't work.

Is it possible to override the default 'IN' behavior such that instead of searching for a basic Profile::User, I can include the different types of users? In other words I want to generate

```
 SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."type" IN ('Profile::User::Member', 'Profile::User::Admin', 'Profile::User::Moderator') AND "profiles"."email" = 'email@email.com' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a so frequent problem that [it has a separate section in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-sti).

The problem is in **constant autoloading**. It queries for all the descendants of `User` *that it currently knows*. That **does** work when classes are *eagerly loaded* (such as in `production` environment). Otherwise, classes are only looked up and loaded where they are referenced. You never reference children in your parents, therefore they're not loaded and don't end up in descendants list.

The section in the guides suggests a solution: require the "bottom" of the hierarchy with [`require_dependency`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency) in the file with your base class (the root of your STI hierarchy). Because, as it turns out, the parent class *does* need to know about its children in order to look for them.

> Only the leaves that are **at least grandchildren** need to be loaded this
>   way. Direct subclasses do not need to be preloaded. If the hierarchy
>   is deeper, intermediate classes will be autoloaded recursively from
>   the bottom because their constant will appear in the class definitions
>   as superclass.

That is, autoloading easily handles going "up" in hierarchy, but can't go "down". By loading all classes at the "bottom" autoloading can follow their parent classes recursively and discover the others.

The guides claim this behavior is not a bug. But, well, it certainly is an anomaly.